# How can I get specific text from a webpage

Tags: java, html, string, url

I've looked for answers to this question on stackoverflow and google, couldn't really find what I was looking for.

When I want to retrieve data from a page, like this one, with this code

```
public class ConsoleSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        URL url = new URL("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
        URLConnection cnt = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
(cnt.getInputStream()));
        String content;

        while((content = br.readLine()) != null){   
            System.out.println(content);
        }
        br.close();
    }

}
```

I obviously get the HTML tags, and everything else that comes with it.
I can easily filter HTML using `HtmlCleaner`
The challenging part and where I find my self stuck is when I want to retrieve specific text from all the retrieved data.

For example, if I wanted to only retrieve text "Nova Scotia" and/or "Europe"... how would I do that?

Comment: have u tried pattern matching

Comment: StackOverflow has an [API](http://api.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank's Andrew. I had no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Nova Scotia"); 
    Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
    boolean b = m.matches();
```

Just look into the above regex package and it will be helpful to you.

Comment: *"it will be helpful to u.."*  Spell words like 'you' properly to be helpful to *everybody*, please.

Comment: He was very, very helpful, regardless of spelling.

Thank you Pratik.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for pointing it out to me. Will keep your point in mind next time I post an answer

Comment: You can [edit your own post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18954975/edit) at any time. :)